# Cannot connect to MySQL database, using Struts2 and jdbc

Tags: mysql, jdbc

I am trying to connect to a database using JDBC and MySQL driver in 
     Struts2 using Eclipse IDE, but I am getting an error as access is denied, Can any one please help me out here ? Thanks in advance

pom.xml is

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>testdatabase</groupId>
<artifactId>testdb</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.struts</groupId>
    <artifactId>struts2-core</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.24</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>mysql</groupId>
    <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
    <version>5.1.36</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

Action class is

```
public String execute()
{
    Connection con=null;
     String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/hadoopinfo";
     String ret = ERROR;
     try
     {
         Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        System.out.println("Driver loaded!");

     }
     catch(Exception e)
     {
         e.printStackTrace();
     }
     try {
         con = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, "root", "root123");
         System.out.println("Connected to DataBase");
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("seems problem with either URL or  
       User and Password ");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

error is

```
  Driver loaded!
  seems problem with either URL or User and Password 
  java.sql.SQLException: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using     
  password: YES)
at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:998)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3847)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3783)
at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:871)
at`com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.proceedHandshakeWithPluggableAuthentication
    (MysqlIO.java:`1665)  




at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.doHandshake(MysqlIO.java:1207)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.coreConnect(ConnectionImpl.java:2249)
at  
 `com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.connectOneTryOnly(ConnectionImpl.java:2280)`
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2079)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:794)
at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:44)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown   
  `Source)`
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:400)
at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:399)
at 
  com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:325)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: I tried by providing default port in URL too, I also tried to grant privileges to mysql database , but error is same , dont know what else I shd do now ?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming, you are able to connect through command prompt (Outside the application)

Run this query in sql editor, and check the result

```
SELECT * FROM mysql.user
```

See if you have an entry as Host `localhost` and User `root`,

If Not : Create one

If Yes : Your password is wrong.

You are connected to Mysql using `%` as the host. Change your password for Host `localhost`

Note: For resetting the password for root, follow this link https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html

Comment: Hi Akhil, Thanks , yes I checked it there is a user 'localhost' exist in that table, using mysql-5.7, in it password column is not present , there is a column 'authentication_string' on its place. I am new to mysql, I tried updating auth_string with new entry, but problem doesnt solve, when I give this is-  DriverManager.getConnection(url, 'root', 'root123') it shows the above error, but if i change password to my new password, it doesnt give any driver error, but doesnt work either

Comment: You should not try editing the password directly in the mysql.user. Follow this link https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/resetting-permissions.html